# Run issue playing a .wav in java

Tags: java, audio

The issue is that the Audio doesn't sound/play when I run this method on Eclipse.
(I've already solved the warning issue on Eclipse):

```
public void reproducir(File sonido)
{            
   try
   {
     InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sonido);
     AudioStream audio = new AudioStream(inputStream);
     System.out.println(audio.getLength());
     AudioPlayer.player.start(audio);
     AudioPlayer.player.stop(audio);      
   }
   catch(Exception e) 
   { 
     e.printStackTrace(); 
   }
}
```

The only way I can play the sound is by debugging the method on Eclipse.
Also I would like to know if there are other ways to play audio (in .wav format) and at the same time be able to know when the audio is playing.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're stopping the player right after you start it.  Are you going to give it some time to finish playing the sound?

Comment: Just noticed that hahaha.
yes i do need to to give it time, that's why i need to know the long

Comment: I suspect that you don't need to `stop` at all.

Comment: But how do I notice when the Audio finished playing?

Comment: That kinda depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  If you know the duration of the sound, then you already have a fair idea when the audio will finish playing.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
public void sound() {
    try{

        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("./sounds/player-laser.wav"));
        Clip test = AudioSystem.getClip();  

        test.open(ais);
        test.loop(0);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```